# Update Array field in progress DB using ODBC

Tags: arrays, odbc, field, progress

I access the progress DB using ODBC in my C# program,
and I need to update some fields,which are array data type.
so how can I write my sql statement to do such things?

I read some progress documentations,in which some methods were mentioned as bellow:
update pub.sometable set arrayfield='X;X;X;X;X;X' where condition....
but it only works on the unsubscripted array.well,another problem,what's the difference between unsubscripted arrays and subscripted ones?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to write the table & field name like so

```
   "table"."field"[1]
```